# Variable length of text with cnn pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am a newbie with pytorch and I am wondering what is the best practice for variable length sentences sequences in CNNs.

I want to use CNN for feature selection on top of word emmbeding generated by fasttext and then feed the output into LSTM .

Now I know pytorch has a dynamic graph and I was wondering if there is a way to this except padding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although PyTorch has dynamic graph construction, it is not possible to dynamically construct different graphs for different sequences in the same batch.
As such, it is possible to perform [stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent), using individual sequences with arbitrary length, but it is not possible to perform *batch* gradient descent without padding.

To make training more efficient and avoid training over padded values, PyTorch has both the `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence` function and the `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence` to remove and then replace padding for batch operations.

```
# pack_padded_sequence so that padded items in the sequence won't be shown to the LSTM
X = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(x, X_lengths, batch_first=True)

# now run through LSTM
X, self.hidden = self.lstm(X, self.hidden)

# undo the packing operation
X, _ = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_packed_sequence(X, batch_first=True)
```